# Creating a PHP Session using jQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On page load, I want to check if a PHP Session variable exists:

- If it does, `alert()` the contents
- If it doesn't, create it and save the current time

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  <?php if(session_id() == '') { session_start(); } ?>

  if (!<?php echo isset($_SESSION['lbBegin'])?'true':'false'; ?>) {
    <?php $_SESSION['lbBegin'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>
  } else {
    alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['lbBegin']; ?>")
  }

});
```

This code works in the sense that the first page load doesn't produce an `alert()` and a refresh shows the time, however every refresh / link click afterwards changes the time.  I was expecting the time to stay the same during the entire session.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you add `session_start()`?

Comment: add `session_start()` on top of your page.

Comment: You have a few mistakes. I have corrected them and posted the final code. Kindly have a look at my answer. `:)`

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, but mixing js and php code is clearly a bad idea, you should think about a better way of implementing client/server communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `session_start()` at the very beginning and check if a session variable exists. Do this way:

```
<?php session_start(); // At the very top! No matter what! ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (!<?php echo isset($_SESSION['lbBegin']) ? 'true' : 'false' ; ?>) {
    // And you cannot do the below thing, because, first PHP executes before JS even runs. So, you need to use an AJAX Call for this:
    <?php $_SESSION['lbBegin'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>
  } else {
    alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['lbBegin']; ?>")
  }

});
</script>
```

Correcting the AJAX Bit:

```
<?php session_start(); // At the very top! No matter what! ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (!<?php echo isset($_SESSION['lbBegin']) ? 'true' : 'false' ; ?>) {
    // And you cannot do the below thing, because, first PHP executes before JS even runs. So, you need to use an AJAX Call for this:
    $.getScript("setTime.php");
  } else {
    alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['lbBegin']; ?>")
  }

});
</script>
```

Inside the `setTime.php` add the code:

```
<?php $_SESSION['lbBegin'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>
```